# change radar image based on button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I could do with some help. I have a radar which displays objects. I'm trying to introduce a radar scan feature so that when a button is clicked the image on the radar is updated based on the tag of the object. My code has no errors but I can't get it to work and was hoping someone here could spot what the problem is. Thanks!!!!

RadarScan Script

```
public class RadarScan : MonoBehaviour {

public Image RadarImageToChange;

public void ChangeImage(Image UpdateImage)
{
    if(gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        UpdateImage = RadarImageToChange;
    }

}
```

Radar Script

```
public class RadarObject
{
    public Image icon { get; set; }
    public GameObject owner { get; set; }
}

public class Radar : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform playerPos; //position of player
float mapScale = 0.1f; //scale radar size

public static List<RadarObject> radObjects = new List<RadarObject>();

//Registers Object to the radar
public static void RegisterRadarObject(GameObject o, Image i)
{
    Image image = Instantiate(i);
    radObjects.Add(new RadarObject() { owner = o, icon = image }); //adds to List
}

//It loops through the list looking for the owner existing in the list, when it finds the owner is detroys the icon
public static void RemoveRadarObject(GameObject o)
{
    //New list for destroyed objects
    List<RadarObject> newList = new List<RadarObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < radObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (radObjects[i].owner == o)
        {
            Destroy(radObjects[i].icon);
            continue;
        }
         else
            newList.Add(radObjects[i]);
        }
    radObjects.RemoveRange(0, radObjects.Count);
    radObjects.AddRange(newList);
}


void DrawRadarDots()
{
    //loops through the list and for each Object it gets the owners transform position and determins the difference between it's
    //position and the players position, does calculations on the angle and distance and position on a circle using polar equations.
    foreach (RadarObject ro in radObjects)
    {
        Vector3 radarPos = (ro.owner.transform.position - playerPos.position);
        float distToObject = Vector3.Distance(playerPos.position, ro.owner.transform.position) * mapScale;
        float deltay = Mathf.Atan2(radarPos.x, radarPos.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 270 - playerPos.eulerAngles.y;
        radarPos.x = distToObject * Mathf.Cos(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * -1;
        radarPos.z = distToObject * Mathf.Sin(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        //grabs icon of players objects and make it a child of panel and set it's postion based on radarPos.x and radarPos.z
        ro.icon.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        ro.icon.transform.position = new Vector3(radarPos.x, radarPos.z, 0) + this.transform.position;
    }
}

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        DrawRadarDots();
    }
```

}

MakeRadarObject Script

```
public class MakeRadarObject : MonoBehaviour {

public Image image;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Radar.RegisterRadarObject(this.gameObject, image);
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    Radar.RemoveRadarObject(this.gameObject); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You aren't applying the Image to your gameobject, only to a variable named UpdateImage. You need to get the image component of your gameobject and then assign the new image to it. You will also need to change the Image to the form of a Sprite for this to work.

```
public Sprite RadarImageToChange;

public void ChangeImage(Sprite UpdateImage)
{
        if(gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = RadarImageToChange;
        }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work with that change. Do I have to change my other scripts to sprite as well? Getting error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I click the button.

Comment: is the gameobject with the RadarScan script the gameobject with your image? otherwise you need to getcomponent on the gameobject that has the image.

Comment: I have the Enemy object that has the make radar script which makes makes it appear on radar and the scan radar script which changes the image to a new one?