# Get image from script attached to gameobject using getComponent in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to introduce a radar scan feature so that when a button is clicked the image on the radar is updated based on the tag of the object with a new image. I'm getting a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on Enemy.GetComponent line in my Radar Scan Script.
but I have a image set?
dot 1 which I will now show below

[image]

Am I accessing it wrong? Here's my RadarScan script

```
public class RadarScan : MonoBehaviour
{
GameObject Enemy;
Image RadarImageToChange;

void Start()
{
    Enemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy");
}

public void ChangeImage(Image UpdateImage)
{
    if (Enemy.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        RadarImageToChange = Enemy.GetComponent<MakeRadarObject>().image;
        UpdateImage = RadarImageToChange;
    }

}
}
```

Here's my radar Script

```
public class RadarObject
{
    public Image icon { get; set; }
    public GameObject owner { get; set; }
}

public class Radar : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform playerPos; //position of player
float mapScale = 0.1f; //scale radar size

public static List<RadarObject> radObjects = new List<RadarObject>();

//Registers Object to the radar
public static void RegisterRadarObject(GameObject o, Image i)
{
    Image image = Instantiate(i);
    radObjects.Add(new RadarObject() { owner = o, icon = image }); //adds to List
}

//It loops through the list looking for the owner existing in the list, when it finds the owner is detroys the icon
public static void RemoveRadarObject(GameObject o)
{
    //New list for destroyed objects
    List<RadarObject> newList = new List<RadarObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < radObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (radObjects[i].owner == o)
        {
            Destroy(radObjects[i].icon);
            continue;
        }
         else
            newList.Add(radObjects[i]);
        }
    radObjects.RemoveRange(0, radObjects.Count);
    radObjects.AddRange(newList);
}


void DrawRadarDots()
{
    //loops through the list and for each Object it gets the owners transform position and determins the difference between it's
    //position and the players position, does calculations on the angle and distance and position on a circle using polar equations.
    foreach (RadarObject ro in radObjects)
    {
        Vector3 radarPos = (ro.owner.transform.position - playerPos.position);
        float distToObject = Vector3.Distance(playerPos.position, ro.owner.transform.position) * mapScale;
        float deltay = Mathf.Atan2(radarPos.x, radarPos.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 270 - playerPos.eulerAngles.y;
        radarPos.x = distToObject * Mathf.Cos(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * -1;
        radarPos.z = distToObject * Mathf.Sin(deltay * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        //grabs icon of players objects and make it a child of panel and set it's postion based on radarPos.x and radarPos.z
        ro.icon.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        ro.icon.transform.position = new Vector3(radarPos.x, radarPos.z, 0) + this.transform.position;
    }
}

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        DrawRadarDots();
    }
 }
```

Here is my stack trace
[image]

Comment: `Enemy` GameObject is not even initialized so you can't use `GetComponent` on it. Fix that then *loadingnow's* answer should work for you. Note that you are struggling with Unity's basic stuff in your last few questions. I suggest you follow one of the Unity's tutorial, understand the basics then continue with your game.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295059/change-radar-image-based-on-button-click?rq=1 posted by you too

Comment: @loadingnow that's weird thought I deleted that one. Wanted to make a new one because I felt that I narrowed the problem down better here on this question.

Comment: @Programmer Enemy isn't initialized? how do I initialize Enemy?. Your right I'm very new to Unity. The unity website is very helpful and a lot of videos on youtube also. Posted here because I couldn't find the correct answer anywhere and you have all been a great help thanks!

Comment: How you initialize depends on what and where Enemy is. Where is the Enemy object?

Comment: @Programmer The game is set in space so I have the Enemy prefab floating above a terrain for the moment near a spaceship.

Comment: If it already exist in the scene/Hierarchy tab then use `GameObject.Find` to find it in the `Start` function and save the returned object to the `Enemy` variable. `void Start(){ Enemy = GameObject.Find("NameOfYourObject");}`

Comment: @Programmer Thank you!. Do I do this in the MakeRadarObject Script? or my RadarScan Script?

Comment: Whereever your `Enemy` variable is declared. That's the `RadarScan` script

Comment: @Programmer Thanks!!!! that removed the NullReferenceExpection but my radar still isn't updating with the new image when the buttion is clicked.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't think I can help with that. I think this will make us go around in circus. I suggest you take a look at the tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

> but I have a image set

Not really. You have a misconception about variable membership and/or how `GetComponent()` works.

The `GetComponent()` method (and it's variants) is used to get a `Component` attached to a `GameObject` ***directly***. It won't recognize/find members (including variables) of the components; only the components themselves;
 even if those members are of ***`Type`*** of `Component`.

This means that the `null` you're getting at `Enemy.GetComponent<Image>();` is not being thrown on the `Image` reference. As you've said, that one *is* set.

---

The problem arises from `GetComponent` itself:

The image component is not attached to the `GameObject`; instead, a ***reference*** of it is set as a ***member*** in the ***`MakeRadarObject`*** component.

As such, **`GetComponent` doesn't find any `Image` component attached to the `GameObject`, so it returns `null`; as it should.**

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that  RadarImageToChange = Enemy.GetComponent<MakeRadarObject>().image; is the correct method as answered by @loadingnow

Comment: @S.Byrne I never said his answer was wrong. =) I only chose to focus less on giving plug&play (copy&paste) code, and more on explaining the problem such that you could figure it out on your own and, most importantly, commit the reason to memory so as to avoid the same problem again. --- Also, *"is the correct method"* is not *quite* right. You'd be missing a `null` check; it should be `var mroComponent = Enemy.GetComponent<MakeRadarObject>(); if(mroComponent==null) throw new Exception("Oops! Forgot to attach the MakeRadarObject to the Enemy object!"); RadarImageToChange = mroComponent.image;`

Answer (score 2):

Each `Gameobject` in your case does not directly contain `Image` as a component, but `MakeRadarObject` and `RadarScan` components.

```
Enemy.GetComponent<Image>();
```

returns null as `Enemy` does not contain `Image`.

However, `Enemy` does contain `MakeRadarObject`.

```
RadarImageToChange = Enemy.GetComponent<MakeRadarObject>().variableContainingImage;
```

Besides, you should be checking if `Enemy` is really an enemy or another gameobject.

Try adding

```
if (Enemy.tag == "Enemy") RadarImageToChange = Enemy.GetComponent<Image>();
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.That code doesn't work when .image begins with uppercase but does when .image beings with lowercase, however it's still returning the same exception

Comment: @S.Byrne That might mean some enemies dont have the `MakeRadarObject` component.  Use `if (Enemy.tag == "Enemy")`

Comment: That's not it, the image I showed above in my question is the only enemy I have and it has the image attached so I'm really confused at this point of what the problem is.

Comment: It should not be `if (gameObject` but `if (Enemy`

Comment: @S.Byrne Try my answer. I focus a little more on explaining your misconception about what is and isn't *"set"*, and why.

Comment: @loadingnow Just tried that thanks but still getting same exception :/

Comment: @S.Byrne Please update question to include full stacktrace. *"still getting same exception"* is not very useful.

Comment: @S.Byrne Perhaps you should show the MakeRadarObject script. It might be the problem.

Comment: @loadingnow I was thinking the same.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate the help, I've updated the question with that information.